# Fabrication gem associations that depend on each other

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, fabrication-gem

The following is my fabricator:

```
Fabricator(:my_fabricator) do
  my_first_association
  my_second_association
end
```

The problem here is that I need to pass my_first_association to my_second_association. Couldn't find anything related in the [docs](http://www.fabricationgem.org/).

Comment: @NoamHacker Is anything relevant other than `gem 'fabrication', github: 'paulelliott/fabrication'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pass a block value you can inspect the attributes hash of the object being generated.

```
Fabricator(:my_fabricator) do
  my_first_association
  my_second_association do |attrs|
    Fabricate.build(:my_second_association, my_first_association: attrs[:my_first_association])
  end
end
```

Comment: Works like a charm cheers, would you be interested in a pr to add this to the website?

Comment: That would be great! The docsite has a separate repo. Please feel free to open issues/PRs for anything you think needs addressing.

https://github.com/paulelliott/fabrication-site